# Conditional statement inside html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this html snippet:

```
<div class="principal-page">
    <p class="main-chart" 
        ...
        <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i> {{$ctrl.voltage}}
    </p>
</div>
```

I want to show the icon and the text only when `$ctrl.voltage` is present (has at least on character).

Now, even without a string it shows the icon no matter what.

Any ideas to do this?

Comment: I think you're missing a tag here. I guess AngularJS?

Comment: If this is AngularJS, are you just looking for something like the `ng-show` or `ng-hide` directive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `ngIf`:

```
<i ng-if="$ctrl.voltage"></i>
```

The icon above will only render in the DOM if the `ngIf` expression evaluates to a "truthy" value.

If you still want the `<i>` to exist in the DOM but be hidden with CSS, you can use `ngHide` and `ngShow` like so:

```
<i ng-hide="!$ctrl.voltage"></i>
<i ng-show="$ctrl.voltage"></i>
```

For further reading:

- [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)
- [ngHide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)
- [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your controller you have a property like:

$scope.voltage = "some text";

Then you can use:

```
<i ng-if="voltage.length > 0"></i>
```

Or:

```
<i ng-show="voltage.length > 0"></i>
```